# How to add button in Content Page to Capture Image using Custom Renderer- View

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, camera-overlay

I wants to develop a Xamarin.Forms mobile app to capture image using native camera with Overlay. I am new in xamarin.forms. i have found below link-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

but there is no capture button. i want to add capture button in Content Page (Xaml page/Shared code) not in xml page.

Please help..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Xam.Plugin.Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)

Comment: thank you for your quick reply but i also want to add **'Circle Overlay'** on camera and crop image. so please share any sample code if you have..

Comment: Please try Circle Image Control https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin or FFImageLoading https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading